# gremlin query to count by path-length all paths between nodes that share the same (specified) label

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have a graph with no cycles.  Each vertex has a label. For those with a specific label, call it "A", I want to count

- how many nodes with label "A" are not connected to any other nodes with label "A"
- how many are connected in a chain of length 2: (A) > (A)
- how many are connected in a chain of length 3: (A) > (A) > (A)
- and so on, up to the longest such path.

I only need to follow out edges.

I have brute forced something related with a set of queries (below) but I want to generalize into one query and not count longer paths with the shorter paths.

```
g.V().has('label','A').outE().inV().has('label', 'A').count()
g.V().has('label','A').outE().inV().has('label', 'A').outE().inV().has('label', 'segment').count()
g.V().has('label','A').outE().inV().has('label', 'A').outE().inV().has('label', 'A').outE().inV().has('label', 'A').count()
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you also want to avoid cycles?  What is your goal with this sort of query - are you attempting to calculate shortest path from every vertex with a given label?

Comment: The system already avoids cycles.  The pattern I'm looking for represents nesting of objects of type A.  I want to know how deep they are nested and how many are nested as an indication of complexity.

Comment: I have a query that counts nodes by label so if its easier to generalize the nested counts query without returning the un-nested count, that's fine.

Comment: If you can edit the question to add some `addV` and `addE` steps that build a sample graph, providing a tested answer will be easier. It is likely that you will want to use a `repeat`...`until` type of approach to solve this. It's possible to do this as one query but it might also be easier to do it as two or three, depending on how complex the graph is.